Realtime events are not appearing using Google analytics Measurement Protocol
They are sent by Measurement Protocol via https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect POST request. Receiving  204 OK, no error, however events are not appearing in GA4.
Have also tried https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/event-builder/, receiving 204 OK, events are not appearing in GA4.
url:
https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?api_secret="**Secret**"&measurement_id="**measurement-id**"
Body for event:
{
"client_id": "12",
"user_id": "3",
"timestamp_micros": "1715935528812153",
"non_personalized_ads": false,
"events": [
{
"name": "purchase",
"params": {
"items": [
{
"item_id": "1",
"item_name": "ww",
"quantity": 1,
"price": 101
}
],
"currency": "USD",
"transaction_id": "t_id",
"value": 10,
"engagement_time_msec": "2",
"session_id": 53
}
}
]
}
Can anyone guide me here what's i am missing here?
I am looking for solution why real time events  are not appearing in GA dashboard

Have you tried sending it to the debug endpoint to ensure that its correct
